# Integral variable in function not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make first function, opt1(), make health go down by 50 points however for some reason it doesn’t work. The code works when not in a function. 
The line that doesn’t work specifically:  `health = int(health) - 50`

```
import random


health = "100"
p = "1"


def opt1():
   print("Du förlorade striden")
   health = int(health) - 50
   print(health)


def opt2():
   print("hej2")


def opt3():
   print("hej3")


q = [opt1, opt2, opt3]
ind = random.randint(0,len(q)-1)


print("you have ", p, " potions")
print("Your health is ", health,)
while True:
   print("Commands: Add, drink, sleep, fight, quest")
   a = input("Enter a command: ")
   if a == "add":
       health = int(health)
       p = int(p) + 1
       print("you have ", p, " potions")
       print("Your health is ", health,)
   if a == "fight":
       q[ind]()
```

Comment: You made `health` a global variable, so if you want to modify it you need to use the `global` keyword. Better would be to not have it be a global variable

Comment: you can also pass `health` as argument to your function, this way it will be accessible to the calculations inside the function as well.

Comment: have you resolved this issue? did you see the answers given?

Answer (score 0):

So I have changed the `health` variable to an int.

And add the `global` to the function:

```
import random

health = 100
p = "1"


def opt1():
    global health
    print("Du förlorade striden")
    health -= 50
    print(health)


def opt2():
    print("hej2")


def opt3():
    print("hej3")


q = [opt1, opt2, opt3]
ind = random.randint(0,len(q)-1)


print("you have ", p, " potions")
print("Your health is ", health,)
while True:
    print("Commands: Add, drink, sleep, fight, quest")
    a = input("Enter a command: ")
    if a == "add":
        health = int(health)
        p = int(p) + 1
        print("you have ", p, " potions")
        print("Your health is ", health,)
    if a == "fight":
        q[ind]()
```

In addition, you can read more on `scoping` in Python [here](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php).

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score -1):

```
def opt1():
```

inside opt1 you should declare variable that you are giving into a function.

for example:

```
def opt1(health):
```